# Error when declaring java.awt.FileDialog

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to declare a java.awt.FileDialog in my code:

```
FileDialog save = new FileDialog(null, "Save file", FileDialog.SAVE);
```

But I get the following error in my console when I try to run my code:

*The constructor FileDialog(Frame, String, int) is ambiguous*

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 constructors for [FileDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) with 3 arguments. Because you passed null as the first argument, the compiler cannot distinguish which constructor you want.

```
FileDialog(Dialog parent, String title, int mode)
```

and

```
FileDialog(Frame parent, String title, int mode)
```

You could use:

```
Frame frame = null;
FileDialog save = new FileDialog(frame, "Save file", FileDialog.SAVE);
```

to fix.

Comment: Aha. Will `FileDialog save = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Save file", FileDialog.SAVE);` work then?